# FuncAnimation with a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matrix, matplotlib

I would like to use FuncAnimation to animate a matrix that will evolve. I tried to use a very simple matrix before using a complex one but I don't manage to use FuncAnimation with the simple one. I tried looking on other posts but I can't adapt them to what I want to do. Here's what I tried to do but it doesn't work

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation
M=array([[0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100,300,300,300,300,300,300,500,500,500,500,500,500,1000,1000,1000,1000] for i in range(0,20)]) 

def update(i):
M[7,i] =1000
M[19-i,10]=500
mat.set_array(modif(i,M))
return mat

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
matrice = plt.matshow(mat)
plt.colorbar(matrice)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=19, interval=1500)
plt.show()
```

I would just like to see the matrix moving to see its evolution.
If you have any ideas, please let me know (even if I'm a little inexperienced).
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work: You have not defined `mat` nor `modif`. 
Also, you should plot to the axes (`ax.matshow()`) instead of creating a new plot (`plt.matshow()`).
The following should do what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation

M=np.array([[0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100,300,300,300,300,300,300,500,500,500,500,500,500,1000,1000,1000,1000] for i in range(0,20)]) 

def update(i):
    M[7,i] = 1000
    M[19-i,10] = 500
    matrice.set_array(M)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
matrice = ax.matshow(M)
plt.colorbar(matrice)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=19, interval=500)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That seems to work exactly the way I want it to. Thanks you very much for your quick answer!

Comment: In this case you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Once you have more reputation points you can also upvote answers that you think are suitable.